# SSAS Calculated Member - how to do percent of total based on another measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I am currently trying to create a calculated measure for an SSAS 2008 R2 cube. In a financial cube dealing with accounts receivable data, I have a "Gross Balance" measure, and a "Days Since DOS" measure. The "Days Since DOS" measure is invisible to the user because it is only used in combination with a couple others to gain an average.

I would like the new calculated measure to show the percent of the total gross balance that has a Days Since DOS value > 90.

For example, if the total gross balance were $1000, the total gross balance for records with days since DOS > 90 being $500, the Percent Over 90 Days calculated measure would show 50%.

Would it be possible to do this with my current setup, and if so, how would I go about writing the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is in fact possible.

First, create a new named calculation in the DSV using a case statement (for example, call it [Gross Bal Over 90]):

```
CASE 
    WHEN [Days Since DOS] > 90 THEN [Gross Balance]
    ELSE 0
END
```

Then, the calculated measure would simply be:

```
Sum([Gross Bal Over 90])/Sum([Gross Balance])
```

You can then make [Gross Bal Over 90] invisible to the user, keeping a cleaner look.